# Select asp:Label text on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a label on my page and want to select the text of this label whenever user click on it so it will be easier for user to Ctrl+C text on this label.
I tried using `SomeLabel.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:this.select();";` but it didn't work. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just double-click?

Comment: @nmat Text can contain spaces and in this case not all text will be selected by double clicking. And on top of that I need to be sure there are no additional spaces selected with this label's text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fnSelect(objId) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
    range.select();
  }
  else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
 }
    SomeLabel.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:fnSelect(" + SomeLabel.ClientID + ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
SomeLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:fnSelect('" + SomeLabel.ClientID + "');");
```